# How to use all the colors when typed in textbox not hardcoded in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, colors

The colors are supposed to be typed in the textbox to draw or add a shape that must change color. This means that when the user types blue the color draw or circle will turn blue. However, I am not getting the result. I chose a circle and it gives a blank. The draw will just draw regular black. I think this piece of code is the problem `gc.setFill(getJavaFXColorMap().get(ke.getText()));` Here are some of the codes. Let me know if you need more of the codes.

UPDATE: down below

```
//colorText will change color used to draw on the canvas.
        colorText.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                    //if the key entered is the "Enter" button, do this following code.
                if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                    canvas.setOnMousePressed(q -> {
                        try {
                            if (getJavaFXColorMap().get(ke.getText()) == getJavaFXColorMap().get(ke.getText())) {
                                gc.setFill(getJavaFXColorMap().get(ke.getText()));
                            }
                        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            System.out.println("It is not working sorry");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the method of all colors

```
public Map<String, Color> getJavaFXColorMap() throws NoSuchFieldException {
        Field[] declaredFields = Color.class.getDeclaredFields();
        Map<String, Color> colors = new HashMap<>();
        for (Field field : declaredFields) {
            if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()) && Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers())) {
                try {
                    colors.put(field.getName(), (Color)field.get(null));
                } catch (SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PaintJFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return colors;
    }
```

UPDATE: here is what I am doing I get Invalid color specification. I tried what you have said.

```
// method for converting string to color
  private Color setFillOfShape(String colorName) {
             Color colorNameAgain = Color.web(colorName);
             return colorNameAgain;
         }

//colorText will change color used to draw on canvas.
        colorText.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                    //if the key entered is the "Enter" button, do this following code.
                if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                    canvas.setOnMousePressed(q -> {
                            if (setFillOfShape(ke.getText()) == setFillOfShape(ke.getText())) {
                                gc.setFill(setFillOfShape(ke.getText()));                       
                            }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`Color#web(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#web(java.lang.String))? You can call that method with "_any standard HTML color name_". For example, to get `Color.BLUE` you would use `Color.web("blue")`. Note that `Color#valueOf(String)` is equivalent to `Color#web(String)`.

Comment: Also, consider using `TextField#onAction` instead of `TextField#onKeyPressed`. The former will be invoked if the _Enter_ key is pressed.

Comment: Sorry if I explained it wrong. In textbox color = "blue"  The setOnAction is giving me error not applicable

Comment: What I understand from your question is if the text of the `TextField` is `"blue"` then you want to get `Color.BLUE`. You can do that via `Color.web(textField.getText())`. It will only work with "_any standard HTML color name_", however.

Comment: I am getting an invalid color specification - gc.setFill(Color.web(""+ getJavaFXColorMap().get(ke.getText() + "")));  Yes, any standard HTML color name is okay.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using your `getJavaFXColorMap()` method. As I said, just pass the text of the `TextField` directly to `Color#web`.

Comment: I could not find anywhere how to get all the predefined HTML colors. I thought getJavaFXColorMap() would solve the problem. Do I have to make a hashmap or how will it not be hard coded?

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding something about your question or there's more to your application than you've explained, you don't need to know all the standard HTML color names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to take the input of a `TextField` and convert it into a `Color`. For example, if the user types "blue" and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> then you should get `Color.BLUE`. This is possible using the [`Color#web(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#web(java.lang.String)) method:

> Creates an RGB color specified with an HTML or CSS attribute string.
>
> This method supports the following formats:
>
> - Any standard HTML color name
> - An HTML long or short format hex string with an optional hex alpha channel. Hexadecimal values may be preceded by either `"0x"` or `"#"` and can either be 2 digits in the range `00` to `0xFF` or a single digit in the range `0` to `F`.
> - An `rgb(r,g,b)` or `rgba(r,g,b,a)` format string. Each of the `r`, `g`, or `b` values can be an integer from `0` to `255` or a floating point percentage value from `0.0` to `100.0` followed by the percent (`%`) character. The alpha component, if present, is a floating point value from `0.0` to `1.0`. Spaces are allowed before or after the numbers and between the percentage number and its percent sign (`%`).
> - An `hsl(h,s,l)` or `hsla(h,s,l,a)` format string. The `h` value is a floating point number from `0.0` to `360.0` representing the hue angle on a color wheel in degrees with `0.0` or `360.0` representing red, `120.0` representing green, and `240.0` representing blue. The `s` value is the saturation of the desired color represented as a floating point percentage from gray (`0.0`) to the fully saturated color (`100.0`) and the `l` value is the desired lightness or brightness of the desired color represented as a floating point percentage from black (`0.0`) to the full brightness of the color (`100.0`). The alpha component, if present, is a floating point value from `0.0` to `1.0`. Spaces are allowed before or after the numbers and between the percentage number and its percent sign (`%`).
>
> [...]

Here's an example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100);

    TextField field = new TextField();
    field.setOnAction(event -> {
      event.consume();
      setFillOfShape(rect, field.getText().strip());
    });

    HBox root = new HBox(25, field, rect);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void setFillOfShape(Shape shape, String colorName) {
    try {
      shape.setFill(Color.web(colorName));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
      Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
      alert.initOwner(shape.getScene().getWindow());
      alert.setHeaderText(null);
      alert.setContentText("Unrecognized color: " + colorName);
      alert.showAndWait();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the strip(); ? I to tested your code strip(); shows undefined for type String

Comment: The [`String#strip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#strip()) method was added in Java 11 and the documentation explains what it does. If you aren't using Java 11+ then replace it with [`String#trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()).